Xen guest with static IP and masquerading with nftables
Determined to turn an old computer into a server (NAS, Home assistant, ...), I decided to learn about Virtualization with Xen Project on Debian.  The server is expected to be used on LAN only and it has the static IP address 10.56.0.191.  I am trying to create a guest on 10.56.0.192 with Xen.
To this end, I followed the informations given in the Xen project's beginners guide and I have been able to create a VP guest running Debian as well.
Unfortunately, the guest has no connection at all.  Still following the beginners guide, together with Xen networking, I tried to configure the host's interface, IP forwarding, ARP proxy, and IP masquerading.  Unfortunately, the wiki refers to iptable which appears to had been superseeded with nftables.  Therefore, I am trying to use nftables.
The guest seems to be unable to communicate (connection tested by pinging various hosts on LAN), while the host can communicate properly.
It seems I am missing something important but I am unable to find it out.  Would you please help me with this issue?
I configured the host and the guest as follows.
I thank you for your help :-)

On the host
I created a bridge, xenbr0, into /etc/network/interfaces as follows:
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Static IP on ethernet
iface enp2s0 inet manual

# Bridge for Xen hypervisor
auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet static
    address 10.56.0.191
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    gateway 10.56.0.1
    dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1 4.4.4.4 8.8.8.8
    bridge_ports enp2s0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_maxwait 0
    bridge_fd 0

The IPv4 forwarding and the ARP proxy both are enabled into /etc/sysctl.conf.
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.proxy_arp=1


With nftables, I created a nat table and a postrouting chain.  Then I added a rule for the IP masquerading.
nft add table nat
nft add chain ip nat postrouting { type nat hook postrouting priority 0 \; }
nft add rule nat postrouting ip saddr 10.56.0.0/16 oif enp2s0 masquerade

Calling nft list ruleset returns the following:
table ip nat {
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority filter; policy accept;
        ip saddr 10.56.0.0/16 oif "enp2s0" masquerade
    }
}

On the guest
Within the guest configuration file, the virtual interface is set as vif = [ 'ip=10.56.0.192 ,mac=00:16:3E:FA:9C:76, bridge=xenbr0' ]
I also trying to configure its network interface by setting a static IP into /etc/network/interfaces:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enX0
iface enX0 inet static
    address 10.56.0.192
    gateway 10.56.0.1
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1 4.4.4.4 8.8.8.8



I don't understand the setup here. The bridge with enp2s0 makes sense on its own, and the NAT rule makes sense on its own, but the combined result is nonsensical – either the traffic is bridged to your LAN or it's routed (with or without NAT), not both, they're contradictory configurations...

Thank you for your comment @grawity.  I am not expert enough to perfectly understand all that networking stuffs.  My understanding is we create a bridge between the physical interface and a virtual interface (VIF).  Then, we need to route the packages from the VIF to the LAN.  (See the picture on Xen's wiki networking page).
Does is make sense?

That diagram makes sense (bridge being optional), but if you want traffic to be routed, then your physical eth0 should not be part of the bridge! Because if it's part of the bridge, and if the VM is told to talk to 10.56.0.1 (which I assume is your physical LAN gateway)... it will indeed do just that, bypassing the host's routing and going straight through the bridge. (And vice versa, the VM's 10.56.0.192 address will of course be part of your LAN.)

Something similar applies to your use of proxy-ARP. What's the goal of proxy-ARP, and what's the goal of masquerade (rather than bridging)? I would have assumed that the reason of using masquerade was that you weren't allowed to bring other IPs and/or MACs into the LAN, but doesn't that contradict the use of proxy-ARP? Is it specifically that the MAC address has to remain that of the host but additional IPs are allowed, or what?

Thanks again.  All those concepts are far from my field of expertise and I certainly need to read more about all of them to better understand what I am doing here.
If I understand correctly, you are saying this should work with the bridge alone.  Is this correct? (I tried already, and it did not work)

If enp2s0 is part of the bridge, then it should work with the bridge alone – the bridged VM would be connected directly to the enp2s0 LAN, assuming that the network doesn't have any special restrictions (e.g. MAC address limits).

Can you clarify whether 10.56.0.0/16 is the actual IP subnet of your LAN, or whether you chose it for Xen specifically? Is 10.56.0.1 the real gateway? Does the network normally use DHCP or strictly static configuration?

The LAN is 10.56.0.0/16.  The gateway is 10.56.0.1
The DHCP covers addresses from 10.56.0.100 to 10.56.0.179.  All other addresses are static.
There is no restrictions on LAN

I removed the IP forwarding and ARP things from /etc/sysctl.conf, and I purged nftables.  Then, I built a new Xen guest image.
Still the same: no mean to ping the host from the guest despite the bridge seems to work well, and the guest's interface is up.  nmap does not show any host on 10.56.0.192 either.

Does the guest at least resolve the gateway's MAC address in ip neigh or arp -an after it tries to ping something (either the gateway itself or something on the internet)? Can the host and guest talk to each other?

When calling ip neigh on the host, it resolves the guest's mac address.  Same when calling arp -an.
On the guest' side, it resolves the mac address of the VIF; but, it cannot reach the gateway.
root@home-assistant:~# arp -an
? (10.56.0.191) at fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff [ether] on enX0
? (10.56.0.1) at <incomplete> on enX0


Of the VIF, not of the bridge? That sounds like Xen isn't adding the VIF into the bridge at all – as normally bridged interfaces lose their identity and only the MAC of xenbr0 would be used by the host. Does ip link ls master xenbr0 list both interfaces?
